# Running both .NET and classic ASP locally using IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic

I have a windows 7 development machine, and my legacy application uses both ASP.NET and classic ASP.

What can I configure IIS7 so I can run this application locally?

Currently anytime I need to test ASP code changes, I have to push to a different server.

Answer (score 3):

We do this at work. We found that you cannot share classic asp and .Net application pools. So make sure that your classic and .Net sites use different application pools.

Configure a classic pool to have "No Managed Code" under .Net Framework and set Managed Pipeline to "Classic." Configure the .Net application pool to use whatever framework you are using and use "Integrated" for the managed pipeline. For us these settings work great.

If you are sharing classic and .Net under one folder. Right click on the classic site, choose "Manage Web Site" then "Advanced Settings..." and choose the classic application pool. Then make sure to browse to .Net portion of the site in the pane on the left. Go to the folder that has .Net, right click on it, and choose "Convert to Application" in the next dialog choose the application pool you set up for .Net.

Comment: app folder has both .asp and .aspx in the same folder, is that what you are referring to in your last paragraph?

Comment: The way we have it set up is a .net app in the folder structure of classic. We do not mix up .aspx and .asp in the same folder so your situation is a little different and my solution may not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can run classic ASP code and ASP.NET code on the same site and application. Most likely you just do not have it configured correctly. If so, then see the detailed article at this link below on how to configure.

[Configure IIS 7 for Classic ASP Support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaskis/archive/2009/07/20/iis7-classic-asp-http-404-3-an-error-occurred-on-the-server-when-processing-the-url-please-contact-the-system-administrator.aspx)