# .NET Core and Classic ASP in the same solution?

Tags: .net, asp-classic, asp.net-core, .net-core

My company is exploring using the new .NET Core for a small internal project, however, there are a couple of very complex (and old) classic ASP pages we don't want to have to rewrite at the moment.

Is it possible within a .NET Core solution to run some classic ASP pages? So far we've not managed, but perhaps there is some Program.cs or appsettings.json configuration we are missing.

Comment: you need to investigate iis settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413998/running-both-net-and-classic-asp-locally-using-iis7

Comment: There is absolutely no way to run ASP within .NET Core, as 1) it's based on the full .NET Framework and 2) uses completely different base. All you can do is run it side-by-side as separate applications and maybe with a reasonable amount of work also may be able to share sessions, but that's it. Just create .NET Core app and do all new development there and move old stuff one by one to it

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Side by side? Yes. Same solution? No. There are [significant differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574489/3191599) between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, and the difference is even more extreme when comparing classic ASP.

ASP.NET Core is designed to run outside of IIS, and .NET Core is designed to run outside of Windows. Classic ASP is incompatible with both of these things at an architectural level.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.